# Cannot install geopandas Pypi package in Databricks (Run time 5.5 LTS Spark 2.4.3 Scala 2.11)

Tags: databricks, geopandas, pypi, aws-databricks

I cannot install geopandas package in Databricks. I'm using cluster Run time 5.5 LTS Spark 2.4.3 Scala 2.11 
The package is successfully installed in other runtime version but not the version I need.
What need to be done to install this package in cluster runtime 5.5?

I'm using below command

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("geopandas")
```

Below is an error statement

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-e9b469dd-aad9-4414-a208-03e3ecd8096c/bin/python, /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-e9b469dd-aad9-4414-a208-03e3ecd8096c/bin/pip, install, geopandas, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. Command &quot;python setup.py egg_info&quot; failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bgvkkr58/fiona/
```

Detailed error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1887950226624660> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 dbutils.library.installPyPI("geopandas")

/local_disk0/tmp/1625551234943-0/dbutils.py in installPyPI(self, project, version, repo, extras)
    237         def installPyPI(self, project, version = "", repo = "", extras = ""):
    238             return self.print_and_return(self.entry_point.getSharedDriverContext() \
--> 239                                      .addIsolatedPyPILibrary(project, version, repo, extras))
    240 
    241         def restartPython(self):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o413.addIsolatedPyPILibrary.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-e9b469dd-aad9-4414-a208-03e3ecd8096c/bin/python, /local_disk0/pythonVirtualEnvDirs/virtualEnv-e9b469dd-aad9-4414-a208-03e3ecd8096c/bin/pip, install, geopandas, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-bgvkkr58/fiona/

    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.executeAndGetOutput(Utils.scala:1403)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.installLibrary(Utils.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1700)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.addFile(SparkContext.scala:1632)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext$$anonfun$addIsolatedPyPILibrary$1.apply$mcV$sp(SharedDriverContext.scala:558)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext$$anonfun$addIsolatedPyPILibrary$1.apply(SharedDriverContext.scala:558)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext$$anonfun$addIsolatedPyPILibrary$1.apply(SharedDriverContext.scala:558)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$recordOperation$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:369)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1.apply(UsageLogging.scala:238)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:233)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext.withAttributionContext(SharedDriverContext.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext.withAttributionTags(SharedDriverContext.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging$class.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:350)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext.recordOperation(SharedDriverContext.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.SharedDriverContext.addIsolatedPyPILibrary(SharedDriverContext.scala:557)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    enter code here
```